# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil, :locale=>:ru}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I added the ability to log into the account through the button (link) in the application, but with the correct routes, I get an error:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Posts#index
> Showing /home/artem/projects/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #44 raised:
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil, :locale=>:ru}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]

But if I enter the link manually (in the search field of browser) - it works (provided that the id is correct)

My users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.all
  end
  
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_posts = @user.posts
  end
end
```

My link(in application.html.erb):
`<%= link_to t('.Profile'), user_path(@user), class: "btn btn-outline-#{cookies[:theme] == "dark" ? "light": "dark"} mx-2" %>`

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root "posts#index"
    devise_for :users
    
    get 'set_theme', to: 'theme#update'
    
    resources :users
    resources :posts, only: [:show, :index]
    resources :tags, only: [:show]
    resources :categories, only: [:show]
    
    namespace :admin do
      resources :users
      resources :categories, except: [:show]
      resources :posts, except: [:show, :index]
    end
  end
end
```

```
rails routes |grep users
                        new_user_session GET    (/:locale)/users/sign_in(.:format)
  devise/sessions#new {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                            user_session POST   (/:locale)/users/sign_in(.:format)
  devise/sessions#create {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                    destroy_user_session DELETE (/:locale)/users/sign_out(.:format)
  devise/sessions#destroy {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                       new_user_password GET    (/:locale)/users/password/new(.:format)
  devise/passwords#new {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                      edit_user_password GET    (/:locale)/users/password/edit(.:format)
  devise/passwords#edit {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                           user_password PATCH  (/:locale)/users/password(.:format)
  devise/passwords#update {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         PUT    (/:locale)/users/password(.:format)
  devise/passwords#update {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         POST   (/:locale)/users/password(.:format)
  devise/passwords#create {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                cancel_user_registration GET    (/:locale)/users/cancel(.:format)
  devise/registrations#cancel {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                   new_user_registration GET    (/:locale)/users/sign_up(.:format)
  devise/registrations#new {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                  edit_user_registration GET    (/:locale)/users/edit(.:format)
  devise/registrations#edit {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                       user_registration PATCH  (/:locale)/users(.:format)
  devise/registrations#update {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         PUT    (/:locale)/users(.:format)
  devise/registrations#update {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         DELETE (/:locale)/users(.:format)
  devise/registrations#destroy {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         POST   (/:locale)/users(.:format)
  devise/registrations#create {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                   new_user_confirmation GET    (/:locale)/users/confirmation/new(.:format)
  devise/confirmations#new {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                       user_confirmation GET    (/:locale)/users/confirmation(.:format)
  devise/confirmations#show {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         POST   (/:locale)/users/confirmation(.:format)
  devise/confirmations#create {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                   users GET    (/:locale)/users(.:format)
  users#index {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         POST   (/:locale)/users(.:format)
  users#create {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                new_user GET    (/:locale)/users/new(.:format)
  users#new {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                               edit_user GET    (/:locale)/users/:id/edit(.:format)
  users#edit {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                    user GET    (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)
  users#show {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         PATCH  (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)
  users#update {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         PUT    (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)
  users#update {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         DELETE (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)
  users#destroy {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                             admin_users GET    (/:locale)/admin/users(.:format)
  admin/users#index {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         POST   (/:locale)/admin/users(.:format)
  admin/users#create {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                          new_admin_user GET    (/:locale)/admin/users/new(.:format)
  admin/users#new {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                         edit_admin_user GET    (/:locale)/admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)
  admin/users#edit {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                              admin_user GET    (/:locale)/admin/users/:id(.:format)
  admin/users#show {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         PATCH  (/:locale)/admin/users/:id(.:format)
  admin/users#update {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         PUT    (/:locale)/admin/users/:id(.:format)
  admin/users#update {:locale=>/ru|en/}
                                         DELETE (/:locale)/admin/users/:id(.:format)
  admin/users#destroy {:locale=>/ru|en/}
```

If you need additional information - write in the comments

I tried: users_path(@users) for link to index.html.erb. That worked correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `@user` is at the most of your pages not initialiazed therefore it returns `nil` (undefined instance variables do not raise an exception) and therefore you path to the user profile is not correct (does not contain `user_id`).

If you want to add a link to the user's profile page to all your pages, you have to  have the user object or at least `user_id` available from all controller methods  rendering `application.html.erb` layout.

I see you have implemented your authentication with Devise. Then you can use it's `current_user` method in your views to get the user object for the currently signed in user. Your link would look like this: `link_to t('.Profile'), user_path(current_user), ...`